# Ionic : ion-content does not scroll on loading dynamic data

Tags: android, css, webview, ionic-framework, hybrid-mobile-app

On a **webview** loaded in an **Android** application , ***ion-content*** has a **div** tag with ***ng-repeat*** to load dynamic data , when the user reaches the end of the page I use ***ion-infinite-scroll*** to load more data.
On Android versions **> 4.4** the container **resizes** and I am able to scroll down to view the newly loaded data but below 4.4 the container's size remains fixed and I cannot scroll down , any idea how to fix this ?

PS : I have tried the following but in vain :

1. Use ***ionicScrollDelegate*** to get ion-content and call ***resize()*** when new data is loaded
2. Try **1)** within ***settimeout*** to ensure resize is called after data is loaded